# retrieving sparql dates in string format

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I have this code:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
    SELECT Distinct  ?bookLabel ?authorLabel ?genreLabel ?date 
FROM <http://dbpedia.org>    
 WHERE{{ {{?s rdf:type dbo:Book .
    ?s rdfs:label ?bookLabel . 
      FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?bookLabel), 'en')) 
   ?s dbo:author ?author . 
    ?author rdfs:label ?authorLabel .       
      FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?authorLabel), 'en')) 

 OPTIONAL {{ ?s dbp:country ?country .
              ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?countryLabel), 'en'))
 }}
    ?s dbo:literaryGenre ?genre .
              ?genre rdfs:label ?genreLabel .
?genreLabel bif:contains "'war'"
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?genreLabel), 'en')) 
  
    OPTIONAL {{ ?s dbp:language ?language .
              ?language rdfs:label ?languageLabel .
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?languageLabel), 'en'))
 }}
    
  
    OPTIONAL {{ ?s dbp:country ?country .
              ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?countryLabel), 'en'))
 }}
    
    
    OPTIONAL {{ ?s dbp:language ?language .
              ?language rdfs:label ?languageLabel .
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?languageLabel), 'en'))
 }}
   ?s dbp:releaseDate ?date.
                     FILTER ( ?date >= '19990210'^^xsd:date && ?date <= "20211231"^^xsd:date  )  
}} }}
```

This retrieves only part of the books for the mentioned period. There are books in `dbp:releaseDate` with dates written in string format not `xsd:date`. for example "2006 February". how can i apply the same filter above for those books?

Comment: you would need to manually parse "2006 February" into an xsd:date literal first - there is no such magic in SPARQL, in your case it would take a bunch of `IF`s to map a month name to the number, but it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBPedia data is mostly just as dirty (or clean) as the Wikipedia pages from which DBpedia is derived.

Your best (if tedious) bet would be to fix the Wikipedia data (making all book publication dates conform to `xsd:date`), and wait a bit (may be minutes, hours, days, or longer, for this experimental public service) for DBpedia to pick up the changes.